How might pagers be made to explode at a controllable moment?
There was this news about exploding pagers - I could not believe it at first.
But now, that it is confirmed, I add my guess as an electronics engineer, how it could work - can someone confirm this construction of a pager or tell the difference?

The pager probably has a vibration alarm, that uses an LRA (Linear Resonant Actuator), consisting of coil(s).
The coils are switched on only shortly in regular operation,
the control signal comes from a processor.
When the coil is permanently switched on, it causes a short circuit of power (lithium battery).
Most probably a transistor (MOSFET, or bipolar) is used for switching the coil.
Even if this transistor is overloaded by the coil current, if permanently switched on, it will overheat and defect = converts into a permanent short circuit - in my experience
then the battery empties quickly, heats up and can explode.
And these pagers probably have a software update mechanism by push message - convenient for the producer to fix issues, but an open door for malware... how well was the update mechanism secured?
or can the processor (used in pagers) simply overheat with a specific program and become a short-circuit?

I saw the damage of a double AAAA lithium battery pack in a cordless phone ca. 20 years ago - the damage stayed in the case, but everything in the battery area + 5 cm (2 inches) further was burnt away/gone ... good that the batteries were placed in the long direction there...
PS: Here the technical background is the only thing asked for.

You're way overthinking these pagers. These are designs from the 90's that Motorola sold off. They use a plain alkaline AA (that lasts for months). The vibrator is an eccentric weight. Many of these were intrinsically safe, I have one or two in my junk pile marked as such.

I’m voting to close this question because the answer requires speculation

A warhead was put in the unit and electrically detonated by the processor.

I'm fairly sure that not every pager that this was supposed to happen to exploded.  There must have been some with dead batteries, for example.  I'm sure there will be people who know exactly what the cause was before too much longer, but whether the info gets passed to the press is questionable.

@MathKeepsMeBusy -- I don't believe that asking how this might have been done requires speculation.  There are plenty of participants here that can list perfectly viable methods to bring about this outcome.  I suppose there's an argument to be made that this info is better off not being available here, but we have no real policy on that, and lean toward not censoring:  https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/402/11684

@ScottSeidman at the time of my comment, the question asked how it was done, not how it might be done. We can only speculate how it was done, unless someone here has direct knowledge.

Yes, then a simple edit turned it into an answerable question.

Still it's a speculation question disguised as a question with an objective answer. How can it have a right answer, and/or how can OP verify that the answer was right?

There is no way that it was a software only hack.
The devices were manufactured with a small quantity of explosives, perhaps some shrapnel material, and a trigger/detonator circuit in place (or modified afterward) by compromising the supply chain.
This has been done before (using a rigged cell phone to assassinate).

Yes, the MSM stories are full of holes, lying, as usual...

There are reports of the devices heating up in pockets prior to the explosion, detectable enough that some people tossed them.  I was wondering if it could have been something as simple as a firmware push that reconfigured a grounded input as a high output, and the short caused rechargeable battery explosions.  This wouldn't involve hardware changes to thousands of units, which would seem like a fairly large intelligence op.

Don't believe every report. This one is probably a fake

@ScottSeidman A feeble microcontroller pin short causing a battery explosion rather then just the controller fizzling out? No fuses? Even an orc would not get away with a commercial design like that. There's more to it...

Having the pager vibrate or beep before going bang might be preferable for maiming purposes. Lots of blown-off fingers seem to have  occurred.
